# Force Emacs to start in text mode

Tags: init-file

[Have been using Emacs for at least 40 years, but still ...]
What to put in `.emacs` so that Emacs opens in text mode?

I have tried:

```
(setq initial-major-mode #'text-mode)
(setq default-major-mode #'text-mode)
(setq-default major-mode #'text-mode)
(setq major-mode #'text-mode)
```

I use:
`GNU Emacs 22.2.1`
`GNU Emacs 25.1.1`

They open always with Lisp Interaction mode.
No need to tell me that I can use: `M-x text-mode`.
And opening a file with a `.txt` extension.
So?

Comment: Say what you mean by open in ___ mode. By default, the `*scratch*` buffer is in Lisp Interaction Mode. Is that what you're asking about - how to have that buffer use some other mode? *"Emacs"* doesn't start in a mode. A minor mode can be global, so I suppose you could say that Emacs is in such a mode, if it's turned on. But major modes are for buffers.

Comment: So far, your question is not very clear. Try providing a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, saying just what you see at each step and what you want to see instead.

Comment: Phew. I do not want to type meta-x text-mode to obtain text-mode. Now clear?

Comment: The mode you get when you open Emacs without specifying any file is unrelated to the mode you get after opening a `.txt` file.  Typing `M-x foo-mode` just before you open a file has no effect on the mode you get for that file.  By default *after* you open a `.txt` file, you should be in `text-mode`.  If that's not the case for you, then there's something funny going on (e.g. in your `~/.emacs`).

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the end of your configuration file:

```
(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)
```

I see that you have tried putting it in your `.emacs` but it could be the case that it is somewhat dependent on where you put it. I tried putting this at either end of my `.emacs` and both worked. The `*scratch*` buffer is in `text-mode`. If you continue to have problems, try using the customisation system to change the value of `initial-major-mode`. Easy way to get there is `C-h v initial-major-mode` then take the option to customise this variable.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the advice.
No success when putting that line at the end of .emacs.
Regarding the approach to customize with: 
    C-h v initial-major-mode:
No idea how that works.
I suspect that 'M-x text-mode' triggers something like:
  (foo 'text-mode)
If so, what is foo?

Comment: Yes, I get the scratch buffer.
The major mode is (Lisp Interaction) - assuming that is what you ask.
Still no idea what is your "C-h v initial-major-mode",  especially
"C-h".  Moreover I want to put something in .emacs so that I do not
have to type "M-x text-mode' when the scratch buffer has ALWAYS (Lisp
Interaction).

Comment: Thanks again!!

Per your advice I made a .emacs file with only:
"(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)"
This produced a buffer with (Emacs-Lisp).
Downloaded emacs 26.3.  This produced a buffer with (Fundamental).
It does read .emacs because it also accepts (display-time).  This is
all happening on window 7 & 8 and ALSO on my ubuntu box.  Baffled now.

Comment: Problem SOLVED. I was changing the file _emacs instead of .emacs.  [Somehow one had to use _emacs in a deep past.] OK now on XP, W7, W8 & ubuntu - with YOUR line.  Thanks a LOT.